# safari canvas drawimage issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, safari, html5-canvas, drawimage

I'm capturing an image from video.

but I can only get blank images when I use  on safari.

But on Chrome It works well.

Please let me know if anyone knows this issue.

```
const [previewUrl,setPreviewUrl]=useState(null)

  const capturePreview = useCallback(() => {
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

    canvas.width = 80;
    canvas.height = 60;

    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    ctx.drawImage(secondVideo.current, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    setPreviewUrl(canvas.toDataURL());
  }, [secondVideo]);
```

I tried both on safari and chrome. but on Safari it doesn't work well.

Comment: What codec is in the video? Which version of Safari are you experiencing the issue on?

Comment: hls and version is 15.6.1

Comment: Safari implements safeguards for HLS. Have you tried taking a screenshot of some videos with your mac? You will notice that it's blacked out. Same when using Netflix, or Disney, etc... It sounds like DRM might be in your way here.